# Cannot inspect Sap B1 SDK objects while debugging in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: debugging, com, visual-studio-2019, sap-business-one-di-api

I am working with **Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition Version 16.7.2**.

I have referenced the **SapBusinessOneSDK.dll** inside a **.Net Core** Console Application to access **SAP B1 via DI API** and I am not able to inspect any **Sap B1 COM Object** while debugging.  The error appearing is:

**“The function evaluation requires all threads to run.”**

[image]

This are the project properties of the mentioned Console App in the Debug Section:

[image]

And this are the Visual Studio Options relevant to Debugging:

[image]

How should I proceed?

Thanks

Comment: How did you reference `SapBusinessOneSDK.dll`? Is it a install sdk? How did you download and use it?

Comment: Console mode apps are in general a hostile place for COM components.  Add the [STAThread] attribute to Main() to try to get ahead.

Comment: @HansPassant you are right, adding the [STAThread] attribute to Main() resolved the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT SapBusinessOneSDK.dll will be installed when installing Sap B1 SDK

Comment: @HansPassant Do you want to answer the question formally or should I answer it by my own?

Comment: First, thanks to `Hans` for sharing the useful workaround and I have added it as an answer to help improve this issue better:) Finally, thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: @jpchauny, you can accept this answer so that it will help other community members search and handle similar issues:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for **Hans** sharing the useful workaround and add it as an answer to manage this issue better.

**Since** you have reference a com component dll on a console app and Console mode apps are usually a hostile locations place for COM components, you should add the `[STAThread]` to get into it.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{

// any code


}
```